# How to update variable of BatchNorm in multiple GPUs in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I have a network that trains the Batch Norm (BN) layer. My batch size is 16, hence, I must use multiple GPUs. I have followed the example of [inceptionv3](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/inception/inception/inception_train.py) that can be summarized as

```
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    images_splits = tf.split(axis=0, num_or_size_splits=FLAGS.num_gpus, value=images)
    labels_splits = tf.split(axis=0, num_or_size_splits=FLAGS.num_gpus, value=labels)
    for i in range(FLAGS.num_gpus):
      with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
        with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (inception.TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
          ...
          # Reuse variables for the next tower.
          batchnorm_updates = tf.get_collection(slim.ops.UPDATE_OPS_COLLECTION,
                                                scope)
          grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
          tower_grads.append(grads)
    grads = _average_gradients(tower_grads)
    apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)
    variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
        inception.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)
    variables_to_average = (tf.trainable_variables() +
                            tf.moving_average_variables())
    variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(variables_to_average)
    batchnorm_updates_op = tf.group(*batchnorm_updates)
    train_op = tf.group(apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op,
                        batchnorm_updates_op)
```

Unfortunatelly, it used slim library for BN layer while I used standard BN [tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm)

```
def _batch_norm(self, x, name, is_training, activation_fn, trainable=False):
    with tf.variable_scope(name+'/BatchNorm') as scope:
        o = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(
            x,
            scale=True,
            activation_fn=activation_fn,
            is_training=is_training,
            trainable=trainable,
            scope=scope)
        return o
```

For collecting moving_mean and moving_variance, I used `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS) 
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    self.train_op = tf.group(train_op_conv, train_op_fc)
```

Finally, the idea of using BN in multiple GPUs can borrow from inceptionv3 as

```
split_image_batch = tf.split(self.image_batch, self.conf.num_gpus, 0)
split_label_batch = tf.split(self.label_batch, self.conf.num_gpus, 0)
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
opt= tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(self.learning_rate, self.conf.momentum)
tower_grads_encoder = []
tower_grads_decoder = []
update_ops=[]
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
    for i in range(self.conf.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
            net = Resnet(split_image_batch[i], self.conf.num_classes) #Build BN layer
            # Loss function
            self.reduced_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss) + tf.add_n(l2_losses)
            # Reuse variables for the next GPU.
            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
            update_ops.extend)tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))
            # Compute grads
            grads_encoder = opt.compute_gradients(self.reduced_loss, var_list=encoder_trainable)
            grads_decoder = opt.compute_gradients(self.reduced_loss, var_list=decoder_trainable)
            tower_grads_encoder.append(grads_encoder)
            tower_grads_decoder.append(grads_decoder)
grads_encoder = self._average_gradients(tower_grads_encoder)
grads_decoder = self._average_gradients(tower_grads_decoder)
# Update params
train_op_conv = opt.apply_gradients(grads_encoder, global_step=global_step)
train_op_fc   = opt.apply_gradients(grads_decoder,global_step=global_step)
variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(self.conf.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY, global_step)
variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())

with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    self.train_op = tf.group(train_op_conv, train_op_fc, variables_averages_op)
```

Although the code ran without error but the performance is very low. It looks that I did not collect BN parameters correctly. Could you look at my code and give me some direction for training BN in multiple GPU? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the performance problems have to do with you doing several variables updates per step (from each batch norm in each tower).

Is there a reason you need to get batch norm updates from each GPU? We recommend just using the statistics from a single tower to update batch norm, as unless there is skew in your partitioning (which will cause other problems), it should work out to be the same.

If you restrict your batch norm updates to those from a single tower you reduce your variable updates by a factor of `num_gpus`.

Comment: Thanks but i am working in segmentation task that Batch size is importance to performance. And they need to train.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you reduce batch size, just suggesting that you only use one minibatch (i.e. one GPU-sized shard) to update batch norm statistics, and have each other GPU only read from batch norm statistics

Comment: Thanks but as you know the inceptionv3 used all batch size to compute bn statistic. I want to follow the direction

Comment: That may be largely a difference in hardware optimization (internally the network is optimized to use our HW accelerators, rather than multiple towers of GPUs), and I suspect won't have much effect on accuracy of the network. But if you are set on doing things that way, you'll have to dig into the batch_norm implementation, to get the actual value of the batch_norm variable updates, and average across towers before applying (much as you do with other network gradients). 

AFAICT there is no precanned way of doing this. It's probably easiest to just reimplement batch_norm yourself.